# How to reorganize PostgreSQL layer fields in QGIS 3.28

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL layer in QGIS, and I have organized the attribute table fields as desired. However, when I copy the features from the attribute table and paste them into an Excel sheet, the organization of the fields does not match what I set in QGIS. I have tried searching for solutions, but nothing has helped.

Here are the methods I have tried:

1. I used the Refactor tool, but it created another layer, which is not what I wanted for my PostgreSQL layer.
2. I attempted to use Python code, but I am not experienced with Python and could not find a solution.
3. I downgraded to QGIS 2.14 to use the Table Manager, but my files always crash in this version of QGIS.

Currently, my only option is to rebuild my project file from scratch. However, I am wondering if QGIS is still unable to reorder PostgreSQL layer fields.

I tried these resources :
[Changing fields order in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240258/changing-fields-order-in-qgis)

[Changed attribute order of PostGIS layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330770/changed-attribute-order-of-postgis-layer-in-qgis)

Comment: A layer based on a PostgreSQL table is a *query* which selects columns in a certain order. If you don't like that order, change the query

Comment: As I understand is to reorder SELECT in the SQL layer?

Comment: What is the problem with refactor fields? Refactor to a temp layer, copy, delete the temp layer

Comment: I want to make the main layer organized because I want the share my project file so the other people who use my project file go directly to the main layer and copy and paste the data to an excel sheet, in summary, they don't know how to use refactor like me